# Android Studio 3.3 click on R.layout.some_layout issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio to latest 3.3 version, and every time I click on `R.layout.some_layout` in Kotlin classes the studio opens the `R.java` file instead of the **xml** file like it was before this update.
In Java files it works as excepted.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After I updated the Kotlin version to **1.3** and the gradle to **4.10.1**
this issue was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Android Studio**, try this:

Select `File`, click on `Invalidate Caches/Restart`. Select `Invalidate and Restart` from the window.

This should clear out all of the previous id resources that were cached in your IDE.

Comment: did not work.it seems issue is in Android Studio 3.3 only